# How to access a structure located within a class from an external function that located in the same file?

Tags: c++, class, struct

I wrote a class for a linked list, in this class I wrote functions like:
Append a node of value val to the last element of the linked list, Add a node of a value before the first element of the linked list and so on...

I want to solve this problem: https://leetcode.com/problems/add-two-numbers/

In this problem, the signature of the function is given:
`ListNode* addTwoNumbers(ListNode* l1, ListNode* l2)`

This is the class I wrote, that contains the `ListNode` struct within it. These are the minimal functions for this example.

```
class MyLinkedList {
public:
    /** Initialize your data structure here. */
    struct ListNode {
        int val;
        ListNode *next;
        ListNode() : val(0), next(nullptr) {}
        ListNode(int x) : val(x), next(nullptr) {}
        ListNode(int x, ListNode *next) : val(x), next(next) {}
    };
    ListNode* head;
    ListNode* tail;
    int size;
    
    MyLinkedList() {
        this->head = nullptr;
        this->tail = nullptr;
        this->size = 0;
    }
    /** Add a node of value val before the first element of the linked list. After the insertion, the new node will be the first node of the linked list. */
    void addAtHead(int val) {
        ListNode* temp = new ListNode(val);
        if (this->head == nullptr) {
            this->head = temp;
            this->tail = temp;
        }
        else {
            temp->next = this->head;
            this->head = temp;
        }
        this->size++;
    }
    
    /** Append a node of value val to the last element of the linked list. */
    void addAtTail(int val) {
        ListNode* temp = new ListNode(val);
        if (this->tail == nullptr) {
            this->head = temp;
            this->tail = temp;
        }
        else {
            this->tail->next = temp;
            this->tail = temp;
        }
        this->size++;
    }
};
```

I'm using VS Code, in the same file I wrote the main function:

```
int main()
{
    MyLinkedList* l1 = new MyLinkedList();
    MyLinkedList* l2 = new MyLinkedList();
    // l1 = [2,4,3]
    l1->addAtHead(2);
    l1->addAtTail(4);
    l1->addAtTail(3);
    // l2 = [5,6,4]
    l2->addAtHead(5);
    l2->addAtTail(6);
    l2->addAtTail(4);
}
```

In the main function I do not know how to access the structure within the class because the function of the solution is outside the scope of the `main()` and outside the class.
I don't know which type need to be `l3` so that `l3 = l1 + l2` and I will use the same signature of the function: `ListNode* addTwoNumbers(ListNode* l1, ListNode* l2)`

================================================================

If I just use the structure given at the problem on the website, without the class and I change the `main()` to this:

```
struct ListNode {
    int val;
    ListNode *next;
    ListNode() : val(0), next(nullptr) {}
    ListNode(int x) : val(x), next(nullptr) {}
    ListNode(int x, ListNode *next) : val(x), next(next) {}
};
ListNode* addTwoNumbers(ListNode* l1, ListNode* l2);
int main()
{
    ListNode* l1 = new ListNode(2);
    l1->next = new ListNode(4);
    l1->next->next = new ListNode(3);

    ListNode* l2 = new ListNode(5);
    l2->next = new ListNode(6);
    l2->next->next = new ListNode(7);

    ListNode* l3 = addTwoNumbers(l1, l2);
}
```

So everything works properly.

My question is how can I use the class I wrote for creating the linked lists by using the functions from my class and and use them to call the function: `ListNode* addTwoNumbers(ListNode* l1, ListNode* l2)` to return the solution.
Thanks.

Comment: Please try a complete re-write of your question where the focus is on an abstract version of your actual question rather than on your full program. Your code probably should be slashed down to a [mre] demonstrating just your specific concern. A review of [ask] might be beneficial.

Answer (score 0):

Nested declaration of classes can be accessed just like namespaces;
Here is test code to try it yourself

```cpp
class TestClass{
public:
   struct InternalData{
      int x;
   };

   int getX() const{
      return myData.x;
   }

   void setData(InternalData data){
      myData = data;
   }
protected:
   InternalData myData;
};

int main()
{
   TestClass obj{};

   //Declaration of variable with nested type.
   TestClass::InternalData myNewData{};
   myNewData.x = 42;

   obj.setData(myNewData);
   std::cout << obj.getX() << std::endl;
   return 0;
}
```

Prints 42

If you don't like to print whole type name, you can simplify it with this construction:

`typedef TestClass::InternalData internalData;`

and use internalData as type alias for TestClass::InternalData.

Comment: Thanks, I changed the code of the add function like this:
`MyLinkedList::ListNode* addTwoNumbers(MyLinkedList::ListNode* l1, MyLinkedList::ListNode* l2) {
    MyLinkedList::ListNode* result = nullptr;
    MyLinkedList::ListNode* last = nullptr;`


In `main()` I added:
`MyLinkedList* l3 = new MyLinkedList();
    l3 = addTwoNumbers(l1, l2);`
But I'm getting an error: 
 `a value of type MyLinkedList::ListNode * cannot be assigned to an entity of type MyLinkedList *`
why?

Comment: @Asaf yes, aliases can be treated by compiler as different type, desite it's absolutely correct to assign them. Try to define typedef as early as possible